# Java not working on Command line

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have tried everything and looked all over this site for answers, but nothing worked. Any ideas? I googled and played with it, still nothing.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sean>set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exe"

C:\Users\sean>cd Desktop

C:\Users\sean\Desktop>javac Welcome.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\sean\Desktop>java Welcome
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\sean\Desktop>

Comment: java isn't found in your PATH.

Comment: the PATH environment setting should contain directories, not individual files. Try with `set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin"`

Comment: It's still not running the program.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sean>set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin"

C:\Users\sean>java Welcome
Error: Could not find or load main class Welcome

C:\Users\sean>java Welcome.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Welcome.java

C:\Users\sean>

Answer (score 5):

You should be adding Java's `bin` directory, not the executable, to the path, at least according to what my own setup is locally.  Try using this:

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin"
```

But you should really update the path permanently from the Windows Control Panel.

If you want to circumvent all of this to run a Java process one time from the command line, you can also use the fully qualified path to `javac.exe`, e.g.

```
C:\Users\sean\Desktop> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exe Welcome.java
```

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sean>set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exeWelcome"

C:\Users\sean>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exeWelcome.java"
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exeWelcome.java"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\sean>set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exeWelcome.java"

C:\Users\sean>

Comment: You're missing a space between `javac.exe` and `Welcome.java` ... can't you see that?  But you should _really_ set the path from Control Panel, so you don't have to keep doing it this way.

Comment: I have been at this for hours. I have done it with space and without space. How to set it from the control Panel? I think I have done that too.

Comment: Try `setx path ...` from the command line

Comment: What did I do wrong?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sean>setx path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exe Welcome.java"
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "SETX /?" for usage.

C:\Users\sean>setx path
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "SETX /?" for usage.

C:\Users\sean>

Comment: @Drolltv65 Sorry, you should just add the `bin` directory, not `javac.exe`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sean>set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin"

C:\Users\sean>java Welcome
Error: Could not find or load main class Welcome

C:\Users\sean>java Welcome.java
Error: Could not find or load main class Welcome.java

C:\Users\sean>

Comment: When you run a Java program, you use `java Welcome`, _without_ the extension.  Also, make sure that `Welcome.class` is present in `C:\Users\sean` by typing `dir` and checking for it.

Comment: That helped. I don't see it in my dir. So now I have to firgure out how to get it in my dir.

Comment: This is my last comment here: Compile `Welcome.java`, which will generate `Welcome.class`, and then run `javac` from the location where that class file is.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That worked!

Comment: @Drolltv65 Is upvote possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one mistake:

```
set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javac.exe"
```

That should be

```
set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin"
```

(... assuming that "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111" is the correct path for your JDK installation ...)

The PATH variable is supposed to be a *search path* comprising a directory, or list of directories separated by `';'` characters.  You cannot add a specific executable (file) to the search path.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Java tutorials are a good starting point to go through when beginning to learn Java. Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#BABGDJFH which explains how to set up the PATH

"Updating the PATH Environment Variable
To set the PATH variable permanently, add the full path of the jdk1.8.0\bin directory to the PATH variable. Typically, this full path looks something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin.

Also , refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html which points to some common problems while setting up a working environment with JDK.

"Common Error Messages on Microsoft Windows Systems

'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

If you receive this error, Windows cannot find the compiler (javac).

Here's one way to tell Windows where to find javac. Suppose you installed the JDK in C:\jdk1.8.0. At the prompt you would type the following command and press Enter:
C:\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac HelloWorldApp.java
If you choose this option, you'll have to precede your javac and java commands with C:\jdk1.8.0\bin\ each time you compile or run a program. To avoid this extra typing, consult the section Updating the PATH variable in the JDK 8 installation instructions."

Answer (score -2):

Can you append java path to your path. This should solve your issue

Comment: The path is there.